# How to show $f(z)=(az+b)/(cz+d)$ is holomorphic on complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was wondering if someone could help me start this problem, please.

I'm give the function $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ where

$f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

I am asked to prove that this is a holomorphic function $\mathbb{C}$/$(-d/c)$. I know that to show a function is holomorphic we need to write $f(z)$ in the form of $$f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$ where $u$ and $v$ are the real and imaginary parts respectively.

Then we need to show that the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ exist and are continuous on $U$.

I started by writing $$f(x+iy)=\frac{a(x+iy)+b}{c(x+iy)+d}$$ which did not get my very far when I tried reducing by multiplying it by the conjugate $(cx+d)-(cy)i$.

I am struggling with finding $u$ and $v$ as my answers get algebraically complicated and the partial derivatives are complex (because of the quotient).

I would appreciate any suggestions or tips (or corrections if I am wrong).

Thank you!

Comment: You can calculate $u$ and $v$ exactly in the way that you have described. It really isn't too complicated. You can also use the fact that the composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic.

Comment: Do you know that polynomial functions (of degree $1$, say), are holomorphic? What about the quotient?

Comment: I know that for polynomials f(z),g(z), f(z)/g(z) is holomorphic but I don't understand why polynomials are holomorphic. I know that if two functions are already known to be holomorphic, then their sum, product or quotient is holomorphic. But how do we know polynomials are holomorphic in the first place?

Comment: @Mandelbrot I did calculate $u$ and $v$ and I got $u(x,y)=\frac{(ax+b)(cx+d)+ac(y^{2})}{(cx+d)^{2} + (cy)^{2}}$ and I am finding this challenging to differentiate wrt either x or y. Could someone please help me?

Comment: You can just check if an arbitrary polynomial of degree 1 follows Cauchy-Reimann

Comment: @Mandelbrot Thank you. But do I not also need to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied (what I would need the partial derivatives for)?

Comment: You are right, my bad. 

You can use the definition of complex differentiability to show that any constant $c\in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(z):=z$ are holomorphic. It follows that $c\cdot z^n$ is holomorphic for every $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$. Since every polynomial is the sum of such terms, we conclude that every polynomial is holomorphic.

Comment: Since no one else has commented this: doing such a calculation using the C.R. equations is removing all intuition. A function is holomorphic on an open set iff it is complex differentiable. The definition of the complex derivative is exactly the same as the real valued derivative, so in particular we have the quotient rule whenever the denominator is nonzero (just apply the product rule); conclude.